# How do I place spinner below the spinner layout when it is clicked and show spinner item in lollipop and above?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-5.0-lollipop, android-spinner

Like overflow menu overlaps the toolbar same way spinner overlaps itself when it is shown drop down item in lollipop and above android version. So I need to place it below the spinner view not over it.

Answer (score 90):

You can use

```
 android:overlapAnchor="false"
```

This will show the dropdown below the spinner view (Work on api level 21 and higher).

Answer (score 39):

For all api use

```
 android:dropDownVerticalOffset="35dp"
```

or whatever value that suits your needs.

Answer (score 9):

Recently, I faced the same issue but I have several spinner across the app and I wanted it to look the same without having to add the same property in all of them, so I used the style.xml to customize my spinners as below

```
<resources>

<!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <item name="android:spinnerStyle">@style/spinner_style</item>
</style>

<style name="spinner_style" parent="Widget.AppCompat.Spinner">
    <item name="android:dropDownVerticalOffset">40dip</item>
    <item name="overlapAnchor">false</item>
    <!--Other customizations-->
</style>


</resources>
```

Answer (score 8):

`android:spinnerMode="dropdown"
 android:dropDownVerticalOffset="50dp"`

This will show the dropdown below the spinner view.

Answer (score 5):

Ues the following attribute  in Spinner

```
android:dropDownVerticalOffset="35dp"
```

Here is the below is code for Spinner

```
    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="45dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="3dp"
        android:layout_weight=".28"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <Spinner
            android:id="@+id/spinner_users"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_gravity="left"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            android:dropDownVerticalOffset="35dp"
            android:spinnerMode="dropdown" />

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="30dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:src="@drawable/drop_down" />

    </RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

It depends on where your spinner is located and how many items in the drop down list.

If the spinner layout is at the top of screen, then `android:overlapAnchor="false"` is enough;

If the spinner layout is around the center of screen with many items, e.g. 60 items, then `android:overlapAnchor="false"` doesn't satisfy your requirement as no enough space for drop down list; and it's the similar situation when spinner sits at the bottom, but with drop down list above spinner.

I think Spinner isn't a flexible android widget as not many settings available, e.g. drop down height, the first item will be selected when loading data. To achieve the same thing, I think `ListPopupWindow` is a good replacement. Here is a simple example of it:

layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" android:orientation="vertical" android:gravity="center">
<TextView
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:text="Tap for more options"
    android:id="@+id/tv_anchor"
    android:layout_margin="20dp"
    android:background="@drawable/spinner_bg"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="40dp"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

activity:

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.act_drop_down)

    tvAnchor = findViewById(R.id.tv_anchor)

    val popupList = ListPopupWindow(this)
    popupList.setAdapter(ArrayAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, getData()))
    popupList.anchorView = tvAnchor
    popupList.width = AbsListView.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT
    popupList.height = 100*3

    popupList.setOnItemClickListener { parent, view, position, id ->
        popupList.dismiss()
    }


    tvAnchor.setOnClickListener {
        popupList.show()
    }
}
```